# How to upgrade Docusign to latest?

Tags: appexchange, data, docusign

We are trying to upgrade our existing Docusign app v3.9.5 to latest version. So I went to the appexchange and clicked on the install button but it detected that we already have the old version and tried upgrading but it failed. so I am thinking i should uninstall the existing old app and install the latest app but I have the below questions:

If I uninstall the Docusign app, Do we lose the existing docusign data from salesforce like the one below:

[image]

Any one has any suggestions on how to solve this issue? The only thing I am worried is that we might lose some data if uninstall the old one and install the new one.

Comment: Yes you will loose the data but you can create a backup and potentially restore it. What was the error you received when trying to upgrade? i would contact Docusign and work with them to get it upgraded. It is not advised to uninstall and reinstall as it would be a project in and of itself

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign requires you to chain relatively older upgrades back-to-back if your current version lags behind the last few version releases. Encountering errors when trying to jump to the latest available version is probably expected behavior.

Use the install links relative to your currently installed version provided at the following page to reach a compatible version that allows you to upgrade to the most recent DSFS package: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Upgrading-DocuSign-For-Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Eric is right that it will need to be re-installed. Are you able to contact your account manager? They should be able to advise what the best next steps will be for your org and to investigate if there's a way to back up the information.

Comment: Just to clarify, I never said is needed to be re-installed. The OP should contact docusign to troubleshoot the error. A little more info about what error actually occurred may be helpful as well. It could be a config thing